# What is the best way to update a question when something changes?

Tags: discussion, answers

Ok, maybe it's not the best title...

There is [a question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35871/left-button-send-to-no-option-to-send-the-file-as-an-attachment-using-evolu) that was really about a bug. Some person answered with a good work-around that solved the problem, it gets up-voted to the top spot, it could even be accepted (not this time).

Something happens, this time I reported the [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus-sendto/+bug/765847), it get solved, a SRU was accepted and the solution is now in the propposed repo.

Now the most voted answer is not the best one. Just updating will solve the problem way better.

What should we do in this or similar cases?

Answer (score 3):

I'm leaning to add another answer and edit the most voted one to reflect that there is now a new solution.

But there are some problems:

- I fear that is rude to the author of the original answer to edit it pointing to another answer (mine).
- It's a solution available only to people with editing privilege.

Comment: all users, even anonymous, can edit: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/

Answer (score 2):

In this case I propose

1. Answer the question saying "This has been fixed ..."

   - Alternatively, edit the top answer with a note of it being fixed
2. Flag the question as being *too localised*

We normally tend to close bug-reports disguised as questions. They belong on launchpad, not AU. But we always like them to be answered before they're closed. It's kind of a half-measure.

Comment: This is clearly too localized in my eyes (bug report AND from beta to boot), we always miss one. Nice work following through on a bug report Javier, well done!

Comment: I missed the beta part... It's closed now. Thanks a lot for following up Javier